# Unable to Change power_profile for AMD Radeon Graphics Card

Tags: command-line, drivers, permissions, graphics, amd-graphics

I wanted to change **power_profile** to a lower one for my gpu/cpu.
And it seems I'm unable to change anything in the folders or subfolders of `/sys/class/drm/card0/device` via combinations of `sudo`, `tee` or complete root command: `sudo -i`

In case you don't know, I have a completely new and clean Ubuntu installation, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

On any of the files, I either get `permission denied error` (even if I run as root) or `invalid argument` if I edit any of the files with `sudo gedit` or `echo | sudo tee`.

```
root@SATELLITE-L855:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# echo low | sudo tee power_profile
low
tee: power_profile: Invalid argument
```

---

```
vaidas@SATELLITE-L855:/sys/class/drm/card0/device$ sudo echo "low" > power_profile
bash: power_profile: Permission denied
```

---

```
vaidas@SATELLITE-L855:/sys/class/drm/card0/device$ sudo echo manual > power_dpm_force_performance_level
bash: power_dpm_force_performance_level: Permission denied
```

**2019-05-29 Update, providing additional information.**

```
vaidas@vaidas-SATELLITE-L855:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +43.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +42.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +45.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +36.5°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)


vaidas@vaidas-SATELLITE-L855:/sys/class/drm/card0/device$ echo low | sudo tee power_profile 
low
tee: power_profile: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please don't bold code or command snippets. instead please use the guidelines here to display your snippets. see [editing-help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)  on how to use backticks for your inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to be root to perform this action.
First elevate to root using : `sudo su`
then `echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level`

This is working for me.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've just created an account to write this answer to you, as I have just ran across the same problem.

I have a hybrid Intel/AMD GPU, so my GPU is not always running.

On my case, I get Invalid argument when the GPU is *not* running. You cannot write to `/sys/class/drm/card0/device` otherwise.

Easiest way to check if it's running is to run `sensors`

```
...
radeon-pci-0a00
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A
```

If temp1 shows N/A or something ridiculous like +511 C, then it is not running. Try running any program that forces your GPU to run. For me I can simply run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears` and it will run in the GPU. After it runs, you should be able to write to `/sys/class/drm/card0/device`.

If the solution does not work, I'll have to ask you to type out the kernel boot params.

*btw i use arch*